# problema no upload de imagem em produção com php

Tags: php, upload

Estou com um problema na hora de criar um avatar para o usuario, em ambiente de desenvolvimento ocorre tudo certo mas em produção ele dispara a seguinte mensagem de erro: Error: file_exists(): open_basedir restriction in effect.

mas o upload ocorre normalmente.

esse é o codigo:

```
mkdir( $target_dir.$nome_pasta);
                    chmod( $target_dir.$nome_pasta, 0755);
                    copy("${target_dir}/avatar-user-placeholder.jpg", "${target_dir}/${nome_pasta}");
```

Answer (score 0):

As permissões do arquivo / pasta não lhe deixam adicionar um arquivo.

Também verifique que tipo de ambiente está a usar, normalmente ambientes linux based tende a usar uma pasta temporária (tmp) antes de efetivamente upar o arquivo.

Seu código aparentemente não há nada de errado.